# Running Unix scrips from SSIS

Tags: unix, ssis

I am trying to run a Unix script which populates our Aged Debt table for our finance department from SSIS but cannot get my head around it. The script has to be run under user "username" and the script to run is :

**P1='0*99999999' P2='2015_03_25*%%*Y*Y*Y' P3='Y*0.0' P4='Y*0.0' P5='Y*0.0' P6='Y*0.0' P7='Y*0.0' P8='Y*0.0' /cer_cerprod1/exe/par50219r**

I believe that I need to have ssh configured on both sides to do this and I believe that I may do this from the "Execute Process Task" but I don't think that I am populating the parameters correctly.

Can anyone help.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do a few things, and feel to scratch off which ones you aren't. (1) You're trying to SSH into a remote machine via SSIS.  (2) Upon successful login, you want to run a script to update a database.  Now, I'm not sure where SSIS fits into this picture, but yes you could use an Execute Process Task to run something like putty/WinSCP to make the secure connection.  Maybe a little more information about the problem could help - like why/how you want to use SSIS for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I currently do this using putty/plink.  Like sorrell says above, You use an execute process task to call a batch file.  That batch file calls plink.  I pass plink the shell script on the unix server that I want it to execute.

example of batch file:

```
 echo y | "d:\program files\putty\plink.exe" [username@yourserver.com] -pw [password] -v sh /myremotescriptname.sh
```

the `echo y` at the beginning is to tell plink to accept the security credentials of the server.